# php json_encode is encoding the same data twice

Tags: php, json

I am getting some data from a database and am encoding it to json:

```
$json = "";
if($result = $dbc->query($query)) {
    $num = $result->num_rows;
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $json .= json_encode($row);
        if($i != ($num-1)) {
        $json .= ',';
        }
    }
}
```

but instead of getting the json string in the format:

```
{"name:"joe", "age":"22", "etc":"etc"}
```

I'm getting every value duplicated because it is giving me the element name as being both the index of an associative and non-associative array. So I'm getting:

```
{"0":"joe", "name":"joe", "1":"22", "age":"22", "3":"etc", "etc":"etc"}
```

While I can still use the json. It is still twice the size that I want it to be and so not efficient. Is there anyway I can get the json_encode method to just give me the associative array inices as the json tags? (Wrong words to describe these things no doubt)

Many thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because  you are using [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) (emphasis mine):

> mysqli_fetch_array() is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row() function. **In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices** of the result array, the mysqli_fetch_array() function can also store the data in associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys.

Use `fetch_assoc()` instead.

Comment: I just realized I've been creating arrays with duplicated content for years because I always used mysql_fetch_array().

Answer (score 3):

Pekka is probably right, but I would like to add that you are making more work for yourself by calling `json_encode()` for every row. It's probably better to build your data structure, and *then* call `json_encode()` on that:

```
$rows = array();
if ($result = $dbc->query($query)) {
    $num = $result->num_rows;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $rows[] = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
$json = json_encode($rows);
```

Marking as community wiki as this is a suggestion on practice and not an *answer*.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with native functions like `json_encode()`, devs are still trying to go to the trouble of manually constructing a JSON string. I see it all the time, it happens in JavaScript too -- people don't realize that there's a `JSON.stringify()` which modern browsers provide natively (and which can be downloaded from json.org to support users without modern browsers).

Comment: Thanks very much for making that point Ken. Your way seems much easier and cleaner. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just change `$row = $result->fetch_array();` to `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: Probably because it is a redundant answer (of yours) and offers less information. I think the gist of this site isn't just giving answers, but giving a little explanation to go with it. Nobody learns anything if they don't understand what they were doing wrong, or why it is wrong.