# JSON value encoded twice : how to use fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, json, pdo, fetch

The following code returns the value twice, once encoded in JSON :

```
<?php
    $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT Date, Open, Close FROM quotes WHERE Symbol = ? AND Date > ? AND Date < ?');
    $req->execute(array($_GET['id'], $_GET['datemin'], $_GET['datemax']));

    $test=array();
    while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
        $test[] = $donnees;
    }

    echo json_encode($test);
?>
```

> [{"Date":"2012-02-29","0":"2012-02-29","Open":"88.14","1":"88.14","Close":"87.60","2":"87.60"},{"Date":"2012-02-28","0":"2012-02-28","Open":"87.83","1":"87.83","Close":"87.77","2":"87.77"},{"Date":"2012-02-27","0":"2012-02-27","Open":"87.41","1":"87.41","Close":"88.07","2":"88.07"}]

I read on [some post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663030/php-json-encode-is-encoding-the-same-data-twice) I have to use `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_array()`.

But the following code returns nothing : `while ($donnees = $req->fetch_assoc())`. Nor does this one : `while ($donnees = $req->fetch_array())`.
I don't get what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See manual.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

You should try:

```
$req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Comment: @pihug12 It would be nice if you marked the answer as right, unless you are dead of course

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what `req` is, but my guess is that it's a [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, which only has `fetch` and `fetchAll` methods (no `fetch_assoc` or `fetch_array`).

You can change PDO's fetch style with the first argument to `fetch`.  It defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (which is like `mysql_fetch_array`).  You can set it to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, which is like `mysql_fetch_assoc` if you like.

```
$req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//global setting
$bdd->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If it's not a `PDOStatement`, then whatever it is doesn't have `fetch_assoc` or `fetch_array` methods.  You'll have to look up how to change the fetch mode for whatever it is.

Comment: `$req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` is OK. Thanks!